# How can I reposition an element with CSS, without risking the browser cutting it off?

Tags: css

In my line of work, we customize pages for clients based on an existing HTML template, meaning the only thing we have access to alter is CSS. So obviously this means looking for creative solutions for problems a lot of the time. Not sure if this can be done, but I need to reposition elements on a page to the left of their original positioning using only CSS. Basically, this element is typically centered, but instead of centering their header image, they need the image to be in the top right of the screen (I've made it the background image), so "centered" for the other elements is now a little to the right.

My issue is that I can only find ways of doing this that cause the element to get cut off the left side of the screen in smaller windows. Is there any way, with CSS only, to position an element to the left of it's original position without allowing it to fall out of the browser window? Sorry if any of this is poorly explained, I do this every day but am totally self-trained. Here's what I've tried (unsuccessfully):

```
.content {
background: #ffffff;
color: #000000;
margin-top: 0px;
position: relative;
left: -20%;
}
```

I've also tried using margin-left instead, as well as adding min-width at 100%. When I tried using position:absolute, it screwed up other elements on the page, so that's also not possible. Please let me know if you know a solution to this issue.

Comment: post the full page code, a diagram of what you're after, and we can help - but this is too vague otherwise, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried following following your explanation. I am not 100% sure if I understand your problem but seems like your issue could be resolved with applying different css for smaller window sizes perhaps. Here's an example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .content {
       // whatever css you want to put here for window sizes smaller than 480px 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could surround the element with a relative position DIV then you can use position:absolute for element content.

```
<div style="position:relative">
   <div class="content"><img /></div>
</div>
```